# Can't get record property of a record

Tags: record, elm

I have this

```
{ a |
    b = { a.b |
        c =
            Utils.newC
                a.b.c
        }
}
```

But the compiler just says "no" :

```
-- SYNTAX PROBLEM ----------------------------------------------------- Main.elm
I ran into something unexpected when parsing your code!

43|                  b = { a.b |
                            ^
I am looking for one of the following things:

     "'"
     "|"
     an equals sign '='
     more letters in this name
     whitespace
```

I don't know what to do now. How to get `a` with `c` property of `b` changed to a new value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updating nested records is a little more verbose in Elm than in other languages, and the syntax of `{ a.b | ... }` updates is not allowed. Here is an alternative:

```elm
let
    b = a.b
    newB = { b | c = Utils.newC b.c }
in
    { a | b = newB }
```

See this related question for more information on standard ways of [updating nested record values in Elm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118128/concise-way-of-updating-a-nested-value-inside-a-record-in-elm-0-18/42118715).